# How to produce blank in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I want to type a `matrix` [x y] with a blank between the x and y. But in mathmode it will shrink the black between x and y. What is the easiest resolution around this?

Answer (score 7):

Add an empty column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    x & & y \\
  \end{array}
\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As suggested in comments `bmatrix` with various spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x & & y \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x\, & \,y \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd also suggest just using `x & y `, which yields the correct spacing, or using the `bmatrix` environment.

Comment: Rather than use the `array` environment, which features rather profligate spacing (in my opinion) between array elements and between the first and last array elements and the surrounding "fences" (whether square brackets or round parentheses), I'd recommend using environments such as `bmatrix` (for "matrix with brackets") and `pmatrix` ("matrix with parentheses"). E.g., $\begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix}$ might do the job.

Comment: @PeterGrill: thanks for this nice and elegant solution!